# Feats for choosing two physical Skills as Class Skills

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, skills

Thanks to the [cosmopolitan feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/cosmopolitan) it is possible to choose two mental based (using int, wis & cha) skills as class skills. However, I can't find a feat that allows the same for physical skills (those based on str, dex & con).

Is there an existing feat I've missed?

If not, I may create a houseruled one myself. But what would be an appropriate replacement for the two languages gained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hermean Blood](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/hermean-blood) is the closest thing I could find, but it requires that they be skills using the same ability score and has to be taken at first level. If you were to make your own, looking at trait bonuses would be a good place to find things to replace the extra languages. Unintentional Linguist is a trait that gives an extra language and a +1 on linguistics checks with it. So its kinda close to having just two languages, seeing as some traits just give a plus 1 bonus to specific uses of two skills. Since it is a feat you could just also give them a +1 bonus with each of those skills. If you are the DM you can make it however you like, otherwise just ask your DM if he is ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are traits for all the physical skills(Fly and Climb) notwithstanding in Ultimate Campaign and thus with the Additional Trait feat, you could get a similar effect. Most traits come with an additional bonus of some form, to 'counter' the bonus languages of Cosmopolitan.